# JavaFX TreeTableView Scrollbar

Tags: java, javafx, treetableview

I want to get the valueProperty of the scrollBar in a TreeTableView in JavaFX.

Both these variants return null:

```
Node nodeA = treeTableView.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");

Node nodeA = treeTableView.lookup(".scroll-bar");
```

Is there another way to retrieve the node of the scrollBar ?

Comment: When are you calling `lookup()`? Lookups will only succeed after CSS has been applied.

Comment: It's called during the `initialize()` method of the controller.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, or at least, the one being pointed to has nothing to do with this problem. The CSS styles are applied automatically for standard controls, and this control (TreeTableView) may have a different naming from the TableView (for which that CSS selector works).